# How to get exit code of a script launched via system() in C++?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, sh

I would like to run a script in an C++ application and capture from it exit code. So I did so in the app:

```
    std::string script_path = "/home/john/script.sh";
    int i = system(script_path.c_str());
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << i << std::endl;
```

I wrote a simple script to see if it would catch the error number:

```
#!/bin/sh

exit 5
```

but the program shows:

```
ERROR: 1280
```

and i don't know why since i'm returning 5 in the script. How could I fix it? I use Linux

Comment: You should extract the exit status from the returned value: `std::cout << "ERROR: " << WEXITSTATUS(i) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I fix it? I use Linux

From `man 3 system`:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> - If command is NULL, then a nonzero value if a shell is available, or 0 if no shell is available.
> - If a child process could not be created, or its status could not be retrieved, the return value is -1 and errno is set to indicate the error.
> - If  a  shell could not be executed in the child process, then the return value is as though the child shell terminated by calling _exit(2) with
>   the status 127.
> - if all system calls succeed, then the return value is the termination status of the child shell used to execute command.  (The termination sta‐
>   tus of a shell is the termination status of the last command it executes.)
>
> In  the  last  two  cases, the return value is a "wait status" that can be examined using the macros described in waitpid(2).  (i.e., WIFEXITED(),
> WEXITSTATUS(), and so on).

You could use:

```
std::cout << "ERROR: " << ( (i != -1 && i != 127 && WIFEXITED(i)) ? WEXITSTATUS(i) : -1) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Nice!  Much more complete.  :-)